# Custom chat bubble for audio in react native chat app

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I`m working on a chat app and I want custom bubble for audio in my chat app in react native

I want to use this type of bubble for audio in my chat app in react native
Can anyone tell me how to do using view I tried but it doen't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the shape and the curve, It can only be achieved with SVG. I can suggest you my package, which can give you a highly customisable chat bubble. You can also ping me for some minor updates and improvements if you'll need any, check the url below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chat-bubble

Comment: I see your package and it's will help me for simple text message but I want audio wave form as well in bubble. Thanks

Comment: can you please suggest me any audio player where I can achieved my actual goal

Comment: My package gives you a wrapper of the chatBubble and it takes the react.children, so you can wrap anything you want inside, doesn't matter if it's a text, an image or the visualisation of the audio you've provided as an image. You will have to handle play/pause button and audio visualisation  by yourself. As per the quick google search results, there isn't a specific library right now which would let you to generate a custom audio waveform right now. But this is an interesting topic and I might consider working on this in the future.

Comment: I just found this one : https://github.com/juananime/react-native-audiowaveform
but I'm not sure how well-maintained this is or if it's compatible with the latest react-native versions..